# Why does this code run in WinForms but not in ASP.NET? 

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

This piece of code runs perfectly in console app and WinForm application.

I want to use the same logic on an ASP.NET website where the data cannot be retreived using `httpwebrequest`.

Kindly let me know how to solve this issue. Is there anything better I can do than this. I have marked the line which is causing a problem.

```
private void runBrowserThread()
{
    var th = new Thread(() =>
    {
        var br = new WebBrowser();
        br.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompletedNew;
        br.Navigate("https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login");
        Application.Run();    // ERROR ON THIS LINE 
    });
    th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    th.Start();
}

void browser_DocumentCompletedNew(object sender, 
                                  WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var br = sender as WebBrowser;
    if (br.Url == e.Url)
    {
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Application.Run is generally used only in Winforms apps. See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034084/what-application-run-does

Comment: Why do you want a windows form control to work inside an asp.net environment?

Comment: Scrapping a site , but its not plain html , it load scripts approx 30 sec then the data is displayed, so i used a webbrowser control. It goes into the documentcompletedevent when all is loaded so i can get the results. Is there any other way? Now want to run same thing online on a website so need help..

Comment: Use the Webclient class. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx

Comment: ahh yes, there is another problem some field are need to be filled and than submitted. So that was another reason to use webbrowser control as i don't have much expertise in making post request. Is the scenario i posted not possible?

Comment: This is a bad way to do it in Win Forms as well.

Comment: @Stilgar Why is it bad?I don't know can you please tell?

Comment: @EhsanKayani - So learn how to do it with post requests. Because your current implementation is not going to work as a web application.  The reason its a bad way to do it, is because its not effective way, All you are doing is showing a web browser control which is trivial.

Comment: OK , last question :) . I mostly use fiddler to see request then duplicate them. But this certain site i don't see any thing in fiddler or console window in firefox . Is there any other tool?Kindly let me know.
Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `System.Net.WebClient` or `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` for this.

Here's a simple example using `HttpWebRequest`:

```
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;

using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{                
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    string responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to go about it another way because Application is only valid in the context of a Windows.Form class.  Even if it was working, all Application.Run would do is run a thread that does nothing.

I strongly suggest you keep this a desktop application, what you are trying to do, is not really suited for a web application.

If you want help you must provide us with more information.  The code you have at this point prety much does nothing of any substance.

Comment: It looks like OP just wants to do some scraping, which is perfectly suitable for a web application. It just can't be done the same way that it's done in a windows app.